# Restricting access to remote database

Tags: sybase-asa

I am using Sybase ASA version 9.0.2.

I can access the remote DB using the `dbisql` utility by providing `HOST` as remote system IP address.

I am starting the database using the `dbsrv9.exe` utility.

Is there any way to restrict the remote access on this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the server with `-x tcpip(localonly=yes)`, this tells the server not to accept remote TCP/IP connections. Or you could use `-x none` to disable **all** TCP/IP connections, though if you're using jConnect locally, you don't want to do that.

*Disclaimer: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thanks Graeme, but i am using jconnect to connect.I just found one link for doing this http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/questions/447/how-to-limit-the-remote-access-to-the-database-server. Can you have a look and give some feedback on this.